# Advice on fixing call to a linear search function for a vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I'm getting an error i have never ran into before. Most likely its something very simple as i have been pulling hairs to find this minor error. So, i have decided to bring it to the professionals.

What I'm trying to accomplish here: I need to search through my Doctor vector and get an id.

Error messages i get when i compile:

```
main.cpp:46:43: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘std::vector<Doctor>&’ from an rvalue of type ‘int’

main.cpp:22:16: error: in passing argument 1 of ‘DoctorIterator DocSearch(std::vector<Doctor>&, int)’
```

I know my linear search function is right, because i have a similar one, but when i call the searhc function i get those errors as stated above.

**Here is the Linear search Function**

```
//Linear search through the doctor vector
 typedef vector<Doctor>::iterator DoctorIterator;

DoctorIterator DocSearch(vector<Doctor> &doctors, int id) {
   DoctorIterator it = doctors.begin();
   for ( ; it < doctors.end() and id != it->getId(); it++) {
     return it;
   }
}
```

**Algorithm for the print bill function**

```
print a bill for (p) { // p is a patient 
total = 0 
print the header information for the bill
for each entry b in the vector of billings 
if b's person-id matches p's person-id 
doctor = search for b's id in the vector of doctors 
print the billing line (date, treatment, doctor, charge) 
add charge to total print the total line 
}
```

**Here is the function that calls the linear search function**

```
//Prints the bill for each patient
void  PrintABillForP(Billing b, Patient p, Doctor d, vector<Billing> billing, vector<Doctor> doctors) {
int total = 0;
cout << "Patient: " << ' ' << p.getName() << ' ' << "Id: " << p.getId() << ' ' << "Ailment: " << ' ' << p.getAilment() << endl;//Need to adjust colum widths
cout << endl;
cout << "Treatment Date " << ' ' << "Treatment " << ' ' << "Doctor " << ' ' << "Charge" << endl;
for (auto i : billing) {
    if (b.getPatientID() == p.getId()) {
        DocSearch(doctors, b.getPatientID);
    }


    cout << b.getDateOfTreatment() << ' ' << d.getSpecialty() << ' ' << d.getName() << ' ' << d.getRate() << endl;
    cout << endl << endl;

    total = total + d.getRate();
}
cout << "Total: " << ' ' << '$' << total;

}
```

Comment: Does `Doctor::getId()` in fact return a `vector<Doctor>&`? Because `DocSearch` expects such a vector reference for its first argument.

Comment: It returns a Doctor's Identification(noting that there are multiple identifications). Ill put my algorithm in the post so you can see what i need to do inside that function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says:

```
main.cpp:46:43: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 
‘std::vector<Doctor>&’ from an rvalue of type ‘int’
```

It looks to me like `d.getId()` is returning an `int`, which is not what DocSearch expects.

Also, you probably don't want to pass objects by value, such as in

```
void  PrintABillForP(Billing b, Patient p, Doctor d, vector<Billing> billing)
```

It isn't clear what the `Billing`, `Patient` and `Doctor` types are, but passing the `vector` by value will result in a copy being made, which is unlikely to be what you want.

Comment: Very good observation i didnt even think of that. I put the algorithm into the code for the print bill function so its clear on what im trying to explain.

Comment: So, i am not sure how i would call the search function then.

Comment: You haven't posted all of your interfaces - what does `Doctor::getId()` return? The name makes it sound like it returns the ID (a number) of the particular doctor. But you're passing this as an argument that expects a vector of doctors.

Comment: It returns an integer id. In the Doctor class it is a private member set as int id;

Comment: Right, but `DocSearch` is expecting its first argument to be a `vector<Doctor>`, not an integer ID. Thus the error.

Comment: Ahh i see, so it would be DocSearch(doctors, b.getpatientId);

Comment: That would certainly make the compiler happier. :)

Comment: I cant believe it took me so long to notice this, as i did the same thing with a similar function and it worked for that function. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

- `it < doctors.end()` should be `it != doctors.end()`.
- `return it;` should be outside of the loop.
- I suspect that `d.getId()` returns `vector` by value instead of by reference.

Comment: in the PrintABill function i call my search function. Basically what im trying to say there is: in the billing file if the patients id is the same as the patients id in the patient data file then go into the doctor vector and grab the patients id that corresponds with that doctor.

Comment: Since he knows `doctors` is a `std::vector`, there is nothing technically wrong with `it < doctors.end()`. A matter of style really.